How to save and resume state for a chess exploration script
I have a small python script that uses the chess library. It simply iterates all possible games from the starting set of legal moves. It ends a branch when the maximum plies is hit, or when a check mate is found. Additionally, it will log the game if it was a checkmate.
import chess
import chess.pgn
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
    filename='chess_game_exploration.log',  # Log to this file
    filemode='w'  # Overwrite the log file every time the script runs
)

logger = logging.getLogger()
checkmate_count = 0
total_games_count = 0

def save_game(board, current_moves):
    with open("checkmates.pgn", "a") as pgn_file:
        game = chess.pgn.Game.from_board(board)
        game.headers["Event"] = "Checkmate Search"
        game.headers["PlyCount"] = str(len(current_moves))
        pgn_file.write(str(game) + "\n\n")

def explore_games(board, current_moves, max_plies=5):
    global checkmate_count, total_games_count
    
    # Check if we hit checkmate
    if board.is_checkmate():
        checkmate_count += 1
        total_games_count += 1
        print("Check Mate Found")
        save_game(board, current_moves)
        return

    total_games_count += 1
    if total_games_count % 100000 == 0:
        logger.info(f"Total games: {total_games_count} Total checkmates: {checkmate_count}")
    
    # Stop if the maximum plies (moves) are reached
    if len(current_moves) >= max_plies:
        return
    
    # Recursively explore each legal move
    for move in board.legal_moves:
        board.push(move)
        explore_games(board.copy(), current_moves + [move], max_plies)
        board.pop()  # Undo the move for backtracking

logger.info("Starting chess game exploration.")
board = chess.Board()
explore_games(board, [], max_plies=5)  # Set a reasonable number of plies (maximum moves)

logger.info(f"Total checkmates found: {checkmate_count}")
logger.info(f"Total full games computed: {total_games_count}")

My question is, how can I save out some kind of state, that can later be reloaded. This would be a long running process. As such, its likely the machine will be rebooted, or the script may need to be moved or modified and restarted. In those cases, I would want to begin the search again where it left off, without starting over.

Simply, you can save the processed boards and currently processing board and saved games in the disk itself.
Im not seeing a check of previously processed boards also. The saved boards will alsoremove some extra computation.
